# Is it possible to loop through the html output in my function

Tags: php, html, function

```
function star_bar( $data = array( ) ) {

    $output = "<b>Rating:</b> ";

    if ( $data["rating"] == 1 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon half\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 2 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 3 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon half\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 4 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 5 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon half\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 6 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 7 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon half\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 8 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 9 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon half\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    if ( $data["rating"] == 10 ) {

        $output .= 
        "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>
        <span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span><br />";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

As you can see this is very untidy, is a loop of some kind possible ? This will output a starbar using a integer pulled from a mysql database.

This is a very simple css star bar source https://coderwall.com/p/iml9ka

Comment: Yes it's possible.  work out how many full stars you need, how many empty stars you need and whether or not you need a half star between them.

Comment: Checkout my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getStars($rating)
{    
    $ratios = array();
    $result = "";

    $lastStarIndex =ceil($rating / 2) -1 ;

    //fill all  
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        if($i == $lastStarIndex)
            $ratios[$i] = $rating % 2  ? "half" : "full";
        else if($i < $lastStarIndex)
            $ratios[$i] = "full";
        else
            $ratios[$i] = "";
    }

    for($i = 0; $i <5 ; $i++)
        $result .= "<span class=\"star-icon " . $ratios[$i] . "\">*</span>";

    return $result;
}
print_r(getStars(10));
print_r(getStars(1));
print_r(getStars(3));
print_r(getStars(6));
```

Comment: i've fixed the code again to avoid throwing notices

Answer (score 3):

### Code

```
function star_bar($data = array())
{
    $output = "<b>Rating:</b> ";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data["rating"] / 2; $i++) {
        $output .= "<span class=\"star-icon full\">☆</span>";
    }
    if ($data["rating"] % 2 == 1) {
        $output .= "<span class=\"star-icon half\">☆</span>";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= (10 - $data["rating"]) / 2; $i++) {
        $output .= "<span class=\"star-icon\">☆</span>";
    }
    $output .= "<br />";
    return $output;
}
```

### Explanation

The number of full stars increases every two ratings: with 0 and 1 you have zero full stars, with 2 and 3 you have one, and so on. Hence, you divide your rating by two, and you get the number of full stars.

You have at most one half star, and only on odd ratings. So, you add it only when your rating divided by 2 gives a remainder of 1 (the rating is not an even number).

The number of empty stars works like the number of full stars, except for the fact that it is based on `(10 - $data["rating"])` (it decreases as the rating increases).

Comment: It works up until the 5th star, int 10 shows half a star and 4 empty

Comment: @Benwhittaker25: it seems to be working correctly for me. Check out my test [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ih2-zb0). H stands for half, F for full and E for empty.

Comment: @Benwhittaker25: your output seems to be the output of rating zero. Please check you didn't input zero as a rating instead of 10.

Comment: i have just checked the database and the number is set to 10

Comment: @Benwhittaker25: you agree that [my test](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ih2-zb0) is correct, though? The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes it works on your test i'm kind of confused my database field is set to int,2 so that should be ok

Comment: @Benwhittaker25: a discussion to solve _that_ problem would be appropriate for the chat, but you would need more reputation on SO. As it doesn't concern neither the PHP code you posted nor my solution (which appears to be correct at this point), let's not discuss it further here. I suggest you try some troubleshooting, and maybe open a separate question if you don't succeed in figuring out the problem.